# Compare cells to delete rows, value is true but not deleting rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare 2 cells and if its true that row will be deleted, i tried using msgbox to return the value and it shows its true, but row is not deleting.
The first cell is derived using formula in 1 sheet and the other is just numbers, does that make a difference?

```
Dim r, s, i, t As Long
Dim com, cc, bl, acc As Long
Dim rDB, rInput As Range
Dim shDB, shInput As Worksheet

Set shDB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Set rDB = shDB.Range("A1", "T1000")

Set shInput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Input")
Set rInput = shInput.Range("A1", "R1000")

r = 2
Do While Len(shDB.Cells(r, 1).Formula) > 0
    com = shInput.Cells(7, 5).Value
    cc = shInput.Cells(5, 5).Value
    bl = shInput.Cells(9, 5).Value
    acc = shInput.Cells(5, 10).Value
    MsgBox (com & " " & shDB.Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & cc & " " & rDB.Cells(r, 2).Value & " " & rDB.Cells(r, 3).Value & " " & bl & " " & rDB.Cells(r, 4).Value & " " & acc)
    If shDB.Cells(r, 1).Value = com And rDB.Cells(r, 2).Value = cc And rDB.Cells(r, 3).Value = bl And rDB.Cells(r, 4).Value = acc Then
    shDB.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    MsgBox ("deleting rows")
    Else
        r = r + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: When deleting rows you want to go from the bottom to top or skip incrementing row counter when you actually delete a row. Also, if you are not using the return value from MsgBox - don't use parenthesis. Your comparison logic seems ok. At the very top `Dim r, s, i, t As Long` means that r, s, i are `Variant` and only t is `Long`. So it is those little things that seem to screw your logic up somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! i redefine the variant, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

When deleting alway go from the last index to the first.  This applies to listboxes, comboboxes, ranges, ...etc.

### If you delete from first to last then you will skip every other row

[image]

---

[image]