# Excel VBA: Delete Old Records

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to delete any records that are 180 days or older. The dates are in Column F. When I run this, nothing happens. I'm thinking that it has to do with the Date() function.

```
Sub ClearOldData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Data").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Dim recdate As Date
    recdate = Cells(i, "F").Value 
    If DateDiff(d, Date, recdate) > 179 Then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows it's best to work from the bottom up, so your row index doesn't get interfered with.  `For i = LastRow to 2 Step -1`

Comment: Good point. I've made that change. Doesn't address the issue at hand though.

Comment: Tim has a point, run your for loop as `For i = LastRow to 2 Step -1` to go from the bottom up, but also you are using the `ws` object (presumably as a reference to the worksheet), but you never set it anywhere.  You can also add `Debug.Print recdate & " " & Date & " " & DateDiff("d", Date, recdate)` to the start of your loop to see exactly what it IS calculating.

Comment: What is the `d` in your `DateDiff` argument list?

Comment: `DateDiff("d", recdate, Date)`  Should have triggered a run-time error without the quotes.

Comment: Also, I believe `Datediff` treats the first date as the earliest one, which means that you may be getting a negative number as the result of the calculation.  You can avoid that with an `ABS` wrapped round the `DateDiff` call

Comment: Following @Dave's first answer, you don't need to `Select` any sheet for this, or deal with the `ActiveSheet`, just maintain a reference to a sheet named `ws`, but be sure you assign to it correctly.  `Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets["Data"]`  Then you can put the `With` block around your `For` loop as well.

Comment: Maybe try changing DateDiff(d, Date, recdate) > 179 to DateDiff("d", Now, recdate) > 179. As per Tim said with the "d".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the VBA Date/Time is a numeric value starting at 1 which equates to #1/1/1900#.

**Date/Time Values**

- 1 Day = 1
- 1 Hour = 1/24
- 1 Minute = 1/24/60
- 1 Second = 1/24/60/60

As always delete from the last row/item to the first.  My answer to [Compare cells to delete rows, value is true but not deleting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755334/compare-cells-to-delete-rows-value-is-true-but-not-deleting-rows/40755406#40755406) demonstrates why.

---

`DateDiff("d", Date, recdate) > 179` and `Int(Date - recdate) > 179` are equivalent.

```
Sub ClearOldData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dimi As Long

    With Sheets("Data")

        For i = 2 To LastRow Step -1
            If Int(Date - Cells(i, "F").Value) > 179 Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```