# Excel VBA Deleting rows based upon date

Tags: vba, excel, date, delete-row

I have a question about the code in this thread

[Excel VBA: Delete Old Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028998/excel-vba-delete-old-records/43116945)

In that thread, is this code

```
    Sub ClearOldData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dimi As Long

    With Sheets("Data")

        For i = 2 To LastRow Step -1
            If Int(Date - Cells(i, "F").Value) > 179 Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem I am running into is that when I run this code, I receive the following error:

*Compile error: Statement invalid outside Type block*

Upon first look, the Dim looks to be incorrect as it is listed as Dimi and I can find no reference to VBA using something like that. I changed it to Dim and it still gives the error. This code appears to be correct in all I have researched on this, but I am scratching my head over where the hiccup is at. Anyone have an idea where it is going sideways at?

Thanks

Comment: Where in this `Sub` do you define and `Set LastRow` ? Also, fully qualify `Cells(i, "F").Value` by adding a `.` like `.Cells(i, "F").Value`. I would recommned to switch to `If DateDiff("d", .Range("F" & i).Value, Date) > 179 Then`

Comment: Two things : 'Dim i as long' (I believe it was a typo in the original post), and as is noted in the post itself: try to avoid deleting your rows on the fly, push every row to be deleted into an array THEN delete each row in the array (starting from the highest value down) to avoid shifting issues.

Comment: As this worksheet lines will flucuate, I figure that the last row after 180 days would be around row 3000.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below, even with 1000 lines, it runs in less than 2 seconds (because you turn `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`)

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearOldData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- get last row with data from column F

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1 ' always loop backwards when deleting cells/ranges/rows
            If DateDiff("d", .Range("F" & i).Value, Date) > 179 Then ' older than 179 days
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You for the code! It is working, but when I run it, it will work and clear out the older lines, but it will then pop up with this error : Run Time Error '13': Type Mismatch and the debug then points to the DateDiff line and as far as I can tell it looks to be correct.

Comment: @RabidWookie  unless it's not form as date, is it ?

Comment: It is just entered in as a date using the keyboard shortcut CTRL Semi Colon and is formated to show as a date (ie 3/30/2017). I did have to modify your code changing three variables. The sheet name changed from Data to Completed, the Range changed from F to G, and the days changed from 179 to 89

Comment: I tried single stepping thru the code and when it gets to Next i, it loops back to the DateDiff. It will do that for 7 times and then gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dimi As Long
```

Whoever wrote that meant to write `Dim i As Long`. If you write a `Type` statement, it looks like this

```
Public Type MyType
    TypeID As Long
    TypeName As String
End Type
```

See how those statements within the `Type` block look like variable declarations without the `Dim` keyword? That's the nature of the error message you're getting. The compiler sees a variable declaration for the variable `Dimi` and no `Dim` keyword and complains that you have type member declarations without a `Type` statement.

If you change it to `Dim As Long` you get the same error but instead of the compiler complaining about the variable `Dimi`, it's complaining about the variable `Dim`. While `Dim` is not a valid variable name, it is a valid type member name.

@Shai Rado gives you working code with things like `Option Explicit`, looping backwards when you're deleting rows, and the requirement to loop from a higher number to a lower number when your step is negative, so I won't repeat those here. This answer just explains why you got the error you did.