# deleting rows with blank cells and criteria VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have columns from A - S, where I need to delete the headers and blank cells, my criteria for lookup in deleting headers are "Transaction" & "Source" but it seems it's skipping rows. I have a total of 79,000 rows but code only goes till 39,000. I've tried everything I can find over. still nothing happens.
I'm also starting the formatting and deleting on row 209 up to lastrow.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Project_M()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cc As Long
Dim dd As Long
lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call ClearFormats
lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
Columns(1).Insert shift:=xlToRight

Range("A209:A" & lastrow).Formula = "=ROW()"   'inserting dummy rows
Range("A209:A" & lastrow).Value = Range("A210:A" & lastrow).Value
Range("U209:U" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(""Transaction"",B209)),ISERROR(SEARCH(""Source"", B209))),1,0)"
Range("U209:U" & lastrow).Value = Range("U209:U" & lastrow).Value

''''' delete headers : only working till row 39,0000
Range("A209:U" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("U209"), Order1:=xlAscending
cc = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(21), "0")
        If cc <> 0 Then
            Range("A209:U" & cc).Select
            Range("A209:U" & cc).EntireRow.Delete
        lastrow = lastrow - cc
        End If

Range("A209:U" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("A209"), Order1:=xlAscending
Range("U:U").ClearContents
Range("A:A").Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit


End Sub

Sub deleteBlank() 'not working
    Dim lastrow As Integer

    lastrow = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B2:B" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Sub ClearFormats() ' working
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  lastrow = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = Range("A209:S" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.ClearFormats
  End If

  On Error Resume Next 'not working in deleting blank cells
ws.Columns("A209:S" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Sub DeleteExtra() ' not working
Dim Last As Long
Dim i As Long
   Last = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step 1
        If (Cells(i, "A209").Value) = "Transaction" And (Cells(i, "A209").Value) = "Source" And (Cells(i, "A209").Value) = "" And (Cells(i, "A209").Value) = "  " Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Sub deleteBlankcells()  '''not working
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cc As Long
lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
Range("A209:A" & lastrow).Formula = "=ROW()"   'inserting dummy rows
Range("A209:A" & lastrow).Value = Range("A210:A" & lastrow).Value
Range("U209:U" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A209),ISBLANK(A209)),0,1)"
Range("U209:U" & lastrow).Value = Range("U209:U" & lastrow).Value

Range("A209:U" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("U209"), Order1:=xlAscending
cc = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(21), "0")
        If cc <> 0 Then
            Range("A209:U" & cc).Select
            Range("A209:U" & cc).EntireRow.Delete
        lastrow = lastrow - cc
        End If

Range("A209:U" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("A209"), Order1:=xlAscending
Range("U:U").ClearContents
Range("A:A").Delete
End Sub
```

I've tried different attempts but not working. codes are commented.
Thanks!

Comment: The loop in `DeleteExtra` won't execute - it should be `Step -1`.

Comment: hi @Comintern ! thanks for your response. yes I've tried `Step -1` but still not working for it deletes everything. I just included it above to get idea. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the If statement inside the For loop in DeleteExtra have Or nstead of And. `If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Transaction" Or (Cells(i, "A").Value)...`

Comment: Hi @nightcrawler23 I actually run it and not working with `and` haha. I'll try. :D

Comment: I've tried using `Step -1` also the `Or` for sub DeleteExtra but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you getting an error. What does it say? Have u chaged the `Cells(i, "A209")` to `Cells(i, "A")`.

Comment: yes @nightcrawler23 I also did change it. it just keep on updating but nothing is happening.

Comment: I'm wondering under `Sub Project_M` is it has a limit of deleting and formatting till 39,000 rows when supposedly has to be 79,000++ , when I'm running it one by one `lastrow' is having 79,000++ rows but when code goes in `if loop` it skips the remaining rows beyond 39,000 rows

Comment: As always delete from the last row/item to the first.  My answer to [Compare cells to delete rows, value is true but not deleting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755334/compare-cells-to-delete-rows-value-is-true-but-not-deleting-rows/40755406#40755406) demonstrates why.

Comment: Hi @ThomasInzina checked on your linked and got it working! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help and ideas of users, I've come to this simple code and got it working.
Credits to all of them! Cheers!

```
 Option Explicit
Sub Project_M()
Dim Last As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Last = cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A209:S" & Last).UnMerge
Range("A209:S" & Last).WrapText = False

For i = Last To 209 Step -1
        If (cells(i, "A").Value) = "Source" Or (cells(i, "A").Value) = 0 Or (cells(i, "A").Value) = "End of Report" Or (cells(i, "A").Value) = "Transaction" Then
            cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next i
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Starting from the last row of the column `for i = Last` up to the row I want to start my formatting and deleting `To 209` and `Step -1` to move up.